# Is it feasible to create an extra field that indicates the number of related entries to be searched in another table?

Tags: sql, django, database

My goal is to get the best compromise between space and performance for the situation. I have two similar situations but they differ slightly.

Situation 1:
Suppose I have two tables for a classic situation: 'survey' and 'question'.

```
class Survey(models.Model):
    survey_owner_id         = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
    survey_title            = models.CharField(max_length=70, blank=False, null=False)

class Question(models.Model):
    survey_id               = models.ForeignKey(Survey, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
    question                = models.TextField(max_length=150, null=False, blank=True)
```

One survey can have up to 10 questions, but may also have fewer, but must have at least 5. I am pondering whether it would be feasible to add another field to the 'survey' table that indicates the number of questions that this survey has, and therefore, the number of rows that will need to be queried in the 'question' table, so that not the entire table needs to be queried from start to end, each time the survey is pulled up. In this case, a survey will likely not be pulled up as frequently. For example:

```
class Survey(models.Model):
    survey_owner_id         = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
    survey_title            = models.CharField(max_length=70, blank=False, null=False)
    question_amount         = models.IntegerField(blank=False, null=False)
```

Situation 2:
Suppose a similar situation as in the survey-question example, but in this case, the survey can only have up to 4 questions (but may also not contain any question), and is being pulled up rather frequently. My proposed solution/question is the same for this situation.

I wonder if the additional used space is worth the improved performance in each situation or not, and whether it makes a difference how frequently the parent table is accessed and how many 'children' can possibly exist in the child table. Any helpful input will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a good practice to add a field like this since you can easily have the information by doing `survey.question_set.count()`

Comment: I agree. It does feel rather redundant / unnecessary / not as clean. But I am unclear about whether that would yet offset the performance impact of doing e.g. 'survey.question_set.count()` as you suggested, each time, or of scanning the entire table to find all entries if the total number of entries to be fetched is unknown (suppose I have hundreds of thousands or even millions of rows, and the access is rather frequent).

Comment: I don't see the point of having such field `question_amount` in your `Question` model. It is a duplicate information and I don't understand how you would use it to fetch the question.

Basically, the SQL query generated by the ORM will find all questions linked to the survey thanks to the `survey_id` ForeignKey. So if you have 10 linked questions, it returns 10 objects. If you have none, it returns an empty result.

Comment: My thought was if the system knew how many questions it would need to fetch from the start, it could stop after that amount (e.g. at 10 questions), instead of scanning the entire query until the end, and so save on processing time. Either I could ignore this altogether and scan the entire query each time (add processing), or calculate the number of items (`survey.question_set.count()`) beforehand (add processing), or use a field (`question_amount`) to readily have that information (add storage use). I wonder which is the best solution in the long run and on a large scale as it will add up.

Comment: I think I don't understand completely your use case with the number of question (especially this part : `so that not the entire table needs to be queried from start to end`). In my mind, it is a bad practise to duplicate the information by adding a field since you would have to update it every time you add or remove a question.

Comment: I agree. And I might have used incorrect terminology. I want to shorten the evaluation of the `Question` query to a minimum to save on processing, e.g. stop evaluating after 5 results are fetched if that survey only has e.g. 5 questions, instead of evaluating until the end of the query is reached. At a large scale, I imagine the effects to be less miniscule than in a single example, but it's a trade-off between space and processing *. I am not experienced with this aspect of DB to determine which is "best" to implement: in the long-term, with many entries, my goal is to be cost efficient also.

Comment: * or a trade-off between processing (standard complete query evaluation until the end, not knowing the total of questions to be fetched) and processing (evaluating once to find out the total number of questions and then fetch only those)